# Only select the fourth TD using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

[image: http://i.imgur.com/L6AU97u.png]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>Friday</td>
        <td>Saturday</td>
        <td>Sunday</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>00:00 - 01:00</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>01:00 - 02:00</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>02:00 - 03:00</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>Show</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hello again Stackoverflow!

I'm using Simple HTML DOM (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to extract the data out of this table. What I want to do, is just select the records for thursday, and extract that to an array with the shows and time.

The problem is that I have no idea how to select only the thursday records. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How flexible are you to add attributes to your table? That is, could you add classes to your cells for something like `<td class="thu">...</td>`?

Comment: depends with what you want to extract them... with jQuery you can do
`$("table tr td:nth-child(4)").text()` this will get the information from 4th td and then you can send them thru ajax to any php file for further manipulation.

Comment: @ChrisForrence The positions are fixed, just the shownames differ.

Comment: @mwebber As said in the question, I'm using Simple HTML DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `xpath` method of SimpleXML to do this

```
foreach ($dom->xpath("//tr/td[5]") as $x) {                          
    var_dump("$x");                                                             
}
```

This does make the assumption that Thursday is always in the fifth spot.